# How can I make a driver for a stepper motor using only discrete components with MOSFETs?

Tags: mosfet

How is it possible to make a driver for a stepper motor using NPN MOSFET instead of bipolar transistors? I have this circuit that I need to make and modify in Micro-Cap. My mentor told me that on the base I need to put two resistors for it to work, but he didn't specify how they need to be.

There's a small problem with the circuit I have too. What is C1?  Is there a replacement for the CD4017 in Micro-Cap?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> is there a replacement for the IC2 CD4017 in microcap

Microcap comes with various digital building blocks, so you could build a functional equivalent of a CD4017 from those. Or, for most realistic results, look up the internal schematic of a CD4017 and replicate it in a subcircuit, using individual NMOS and PMOS devices just as would be done on the chip itself.

> I have this scheme that I need to make and modify in microcap.

Wouldn't it be easier to just put it together on the breadboard and measure the performance with a basic digital oscilloscope? I suggest you still do that after you get the microcap model working.

> How is it possible to make a driver for a stepper motor using NPN mosfet instead of bipolar transistors.

Mosfets are called N-MOS, not NPN-MOS. NPN implies two semiconductor junctions. Mosfets don't have two, they just have an N or P channel, an isolated gate, and an inherent body-channel diode. N-MOS means an N-channel device, implied to be enhancement mode.

In the particular cirucit you've shown, the NPN transistors can be replaced with 2N7000 N-mosfets.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj0dRb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 2N7000 symbol above includes the body diode, just to visualize it - the diode is there whether you show it or not :) The body diode provides additional overshoot protection for the switched node, and in that respect the mosfet is better for the job than an NPN transistor is. For an NPN transistor, you'd need a second protection diode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJdBGj.png)</sup>

The NPN transistors also could use a series resistor on the base, to keep the CD4017 output stage dissipation low. Since CD4017 has only one output active at a time, not having those series resistors in not a big deal. CD4000-series logic outputs are inherently current limiting, so "shorting" them through the Base-Emitter diode to ground is not the worst thing in this case.